# Get ID of slider element activated in jQuery.each()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a number of sliders defined in a container div like

```
  <div id="opacitySlider" class='slider'>
    <div class="sliderText">Fade Opacity</div>
    <div id="fadeVal"></div>
  </div>
```

and many more

They are controlled by the jQuery UI `slider()` functionality defined as

```
$(".slider").each(function(e){
  $(this).slider({
    value: 50,
    orientation: 'horizontal',
    animate: true,
    range: 'min',
    slide: function(e, ui){
      console.log($(e).id);
      console.log($(this).id;
    }
  });
});
```

What I want to do is update the slider value div with the value of the associated slider

Both the console logging statements return undefined.  I need to know the ID of the slider that's firing off the events to update the correct div element.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.each()` has two arguments, the first being the index, the second being the element:

```
$(".slider").each(function(i, e) {
    $(e).slider({
        value: 50,
        orientation: 'horizontal',
        animate: true,
        range: 'min',
        slide: function(e, ui) {
            console.log(this.id); //new scope
        }
    });
});​
```

When doing only `$(".slider").each(function(e) {...}`, then `e` will be the index and not the element, so you are trying to get the ID for the numbers 0, 1, 2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Should be
`$(this).attr('id');` or `$(e).attr('id');`

Comment: @wirey: You're right. I just tend to stick to the jquery variant, otherwise it can be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".slider").each(function(e){

  var curSlider = $(this);

  $(this).slider({
    value: 50,
    orientation: 'horizontal',
    animate: true,
    range: 'min',
    slide: function(e, ui){

      console.log(curSlider.attr('id'));

    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `id` property of `this` or `e.target`:

```
slide: function(e, ui){
  console.log(this.id);
  //or
  console.log(e.target.id);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ynRwL/)